# BindableCollection and NotifyOfPropertyChange

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

While messing around with Caliburn Micro, I had a DataGrid named MyCollection, which uses conventions to set the Itemsource to a collection named MyCollection in my viewmodel. I declared it like this:

```
public BindableCollection<ModelClass> MyCollection{ get; set; }
```

When I run, I get no items, so I change it to

```
 public BindableCollection<ModelClass> MyCollection
    {
        get => _myCollection;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _myCollection)) return;
            _myCollection= value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyCollection);
        }
    }
```

and it works. I had noticed that BindableCollection has an IsNotifying property, and it's a subclass of ObservableCollection. I thought this meant it would fire the NotifyOfPropertyChange's automatically, so I figure I'm misunderstanding the purpose of these collections.

Can someone help me understand?

Comment: BindableCollection can't notify about a property in a different class, e.g. your MyCollection property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection<T>` provides notifications to the UI when items get added or removed from the collection and when the whole collection is refreshed.

It does however not notify the view when the `MyCollection` property is set to a new collection. So if you are assigning the `MyCollection` property dynamically after the view has been loaded, you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `MyCollection` source property for the view to be reloaded with the new collection.